# Cannot enter text into form (Flask, WTForm)

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I want to build a website with Flask and WTForms. But I cannot get the text input to work (The page will not let me enter any text into the boxes). Can you show me what is wrong?

This is what the page looks like:

[image]

This is the form I created with WTForms

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, NumberRange, EqualTo


class RequestDataForm(FlaskForm):

    feature_count = IntegerField('Number of features', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1, max=50)])

    effective_rank = IntegerField('Effective Rank', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1, max=EqualTo(feature_count))])

    noise = IntegerField('Noise', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=1)])

    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

This is the `layout.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
</style>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            {% if messages %}
              {% for category, message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
                  {{ message }}
                </div>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endwith %}
          {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my `page.html`

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block page_content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Fill with values.</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.feature_count.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.feature_count.label(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.effective_rank.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.effective_rank.label(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.noise.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.noise.label(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock page_content%}
```

Comment: you're using IntegerField's...why would it allow text?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want numerical input, so I assumed I would have to use IntegerFields....

Comment: You do, so why are you trying to enter text?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone The issue is that I cannot even select the field and enter anything (neither numbers nor any other text).

Comment: You seem to only be outputting `label`s?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone Yes, for some reason the labels appear inside the fields...

Comment: @Philipp what do you mean? You aren't outputting the fields anywhere.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone You are probably right, let me just check if your tip works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your HTML you are only outputting the `label` for each form element not the element itself. Try updating them all to:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.noise.label(class="form-control-label") }}
    {{ form.noise(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
</div>
```